# Download different files according to browser language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How can I download different files according to the lang attribute in HTML?

Currently, my code is looking like this:

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

import ENCV from "../assets/englishCV.pdf";
import PTCV from "../assets/portugueseCV.pdf";

const CTA = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const onDownloadCV = () => {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang") === "pt") {      
        }
    };

    return(
        <div className="cta">
            <a href={} download className="btn">{t("downloadCV")}</a>
            <a href="#contact" className="btn btn-primary">{t("contactButton")}</a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CTA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename to what contains the lang attribute.

e.g. "cv_pt" or "cv_en".

Then you can get the target file with the lang attribute.

```
const onDownloadCV = async () => {
  const lang = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");
  const targetCV = await require(`../assets/cv_${lang}.pdf`);
  ... ... ...
};
```

Comment: Awesome! How would I be able to reference targetCV on href?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `i18next`, it would be better to get the current language directly from `i18next` instead of the DOM:

```js
import i18next from "i18next";

// inside component:
const lang = i18next.language;
// lang will be string such as: "en", "fr", ...
// now you can use it to specify the relevant language file.
...
```

Comment: Makes total sense. But, since <a> tag is a button, how do I pass a function as href?

Comment: Instead of passing a function, you can just set `href` directly. However, if you need to use a function e.g. for side effects, you can still do that by passing `onClick` prop to `<a />`, and within the function you may do `event.preventDefault()` if you need to.